# How to stop fadeIn() blinking?

Tags: jquery

Currently I have a simple div that I want to have fade in on mouseover of another div, but it would blink 3 times.

I've read some of the other questions and I think this has to do with how my code is structured. But I'm not sure how to correct mine as it's so basic already.

Here are my codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.content .guide ul.guide li .event').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).find('.info').fadeIn();
        });
        $('.content .guide ul.guide li .event').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find('.info').fadeOut();
        });
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
.content .guide ul.guide li .event .info {display:none;}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="guide">
    <li class="mon">
        <div class="day">Monday</div>
        <div class="session-1 event">
            <time>7:30am</time>
            <span>Ep 5: <a href="">Lorem</a></span>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="tooltip"></div>
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="desc">Ep 8: Lorem ipsum</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="session-2 event">
            <time>8:30pm</time>
            <span>Ep 5: <a href="">Lorem</a></span>
            <div class="info">
                <div class="tooltip"></div>
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="desc">Ep 8: Lorem ipsum</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="tue">
        <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
        <div class="session-1">
        </div>
        <div class="session-2">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but note that you should chain your `mouseover` and `mouseout` methods to avoid creating the same jQuery object twice: `$('.content .guide ul.guide li .event').mouseover(function(){ ... }).mouseout(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `stop().fadeTo()` to prevent that.
See below code and [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/CN6Uw/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.content .guide ul.guide li .event').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).find('.info').stop().fadeTo('slow',1);
        });
        $('.content .guide ul.guide li .event').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find('.info').stop().fadeTo('slow',0);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just to note that `fadeTo` is nothing special, and all the magic is in `stop`: `.stop().fadeIn()` and `.stop().fadeOut()` work as well.

Comment: I was about to give the same answer. Here's the fiddle I created for it: http://jsfiddle.net/MnwTN/ Note that you may want `.stop(true,true)` (otherwise, depending on how you manoeuvre the mouse, you may end up with the element faded out even though you're still over it). I'd give you a +1 if you explained _why_ this fixes things...

Comment: @nnnnnn the first 'true' clears the animation queue and the second 'true' jumps to the end of the current animation. http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: @Jeff - yes, I know. I meant I'd upvote the answer if Dips added a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 8):

I only got this problem in Google Chrome.

I've changed `.fadeIn` to `.fadeTo(myDuration,1)` to fix it.

Also, for me, everything works fine without `.stop()`.

Answer (score 4):

I had this and this solved my problem ( I was using fadeIn and fadeOut)

```
$( "#board" ).stop().animate({ "opacity": 1 },300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I wanted to add my findings after fighting this problem, in case they are helpful to anyone who stumbles across this question.

When using stop().fadeIn(), it would simply pause the action, until the next one is triggered.

Instead of stop(), I then tried finish().fadeIn(), and finish().fadeOut(). This worked much better. The currently ongoing animation is finished immediately, and the current is started.

For the above example, it would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.content .guide ul.guide li .event').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).find('.info').finish().fadeTo('slow',1);
        });
        $('.content .guide ul.guide li .event').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find('.info').finish().fadeTo('slow',0);
        });
    });
</script>
```