# Change opacity on image attribute change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am changing image source on click (prev/next buttons), and I would like to fade out image, then change source and fade it in, but I cannot get smooth transition. I tried adding `.delay()` in between fading and changing the source but still the `src` change happens before fading ends. I tried adding `.stop()` but that only stops the currently running animation, and attribute change doesn't count as animation.

```js
var images = ['http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/kVy4G4R.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/BtMikrd.jpg'];

var count = 0;

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  if (count !== images.length-1) {
    count++;
    $('.product_image img').fadeTo(300, 0).delay(600).attr('src', '').attr('src', images[count]).fadeTo(300, 1);
  }
});

$('.previous').on('click', function() {
  if (count !== 0) {
    count--;
    $('.product_image img').fadeTo(300, 0).delay(400).attr('src', '').attr('src', images[count]).fadeTo(300, 1);
  }
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  display: block;
}
.navigation .previous,
.navigation .next {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navigation .next {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_image">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="previous">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a callback function of the first `fadeTo`, otherwise the images are faded out, changed and faded back in again all at the same time. Try this:

```js
var images = ['http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/kVy4G4R.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/BtMikrd.jpg'];
var count = 0;

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  if (count !== images.length - 1) {
    count++;
    $('.product_image img').fadeTo(300, 0, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', images[count]).fadeTo(300, 1);
    });
  }
});
$('.previous').on('click', function() {
  if (count !== 0) {
    count--;
    $('.product_image img').fadeTo(300, 0, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', images[count]).fadeTo(300, 1);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  display: block;
}
.navigation .previous,
.navigation .next {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navigation .next {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_image">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="previous">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

## Use a callback function

I would suggest using the `complete` callback which is documented **[here](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/)**.

The callback is defined as a function and is added after the opacity value like this:

```
.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, complete ] )
```

The callback function will then fire after the animation has completed allowing us to change the `src` attribute while the image is "hidden" and then fading it back in.

### An Example

```js
var images = ['http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/kVy4G4R.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/BtMikrd.jpg'];

var count = 0,
    productImage = $('.product_image').children('img');

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  
  if (count !== images.length - 1) {
    
    count++;
    
    productImage.fadeTo(300, 0, function() {

      productImage.attr('src', images[count]).fadeTo(300, 1);

    });
  }
});

$('.previous').on('click', function() {
  
  if (count !== 0) {
    
    count--;
    
    productImage.fadeTo(300, 0, function() {

      productImage.attr('src', images[count]).fadeTo(300, 1);

    });
  }
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  display: block;
}
.navigation .previous,
.navigation .next {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navigation .next {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_image">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="previous">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.attr()` function is not a queue based method, so the delay will not have any effect on it. You can use `.delay()` to add a method to the animation queue.

Also preloading the images can improve the transition.

```js
var images = ['http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/kVy4G4R.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/BtMikrd.jpg'];

//image preloading
images.forEach(function(src) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
})

var count = 0;

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  count++;
  count = count >= images.length ? 0 : count;
  $('.product_image img').fadeTo(300, 0).delay(600).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).attr('src', images[count]);
    next();
  }).fadeTo(300, 1);
});

$('.previous').on('click', function() {
  count--;
  count = count < 0 ? images.length - 1 : count;

  $('.product_image img').fadeTo(300, 0).delay(400).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).attr('src', images[count]);
    next();
  }).fadeTo(300, 1);
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  display: block;
}
.navigation .previous,
.navigation .next {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navigation .next {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_image">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="previous">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach

```
$(img).fadeTo(200,0.70, function() {
        $(img).attr("src", new_img_src);
   }).fadeTo(300,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20830749): currently ongoing animation is finished immediately, and the current is started.

```js
var images = ['http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/kVy4G4R.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/BtMikrd.jpg'];

var count = 0;

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  if (count !== images.length-1) {
    count++;
    $('.product_image img').fadeTo(300, 0).delay(600).attr('src', '').attr('src', images[count]).finish().fadeTo(300, 1);
  }
});

$('.previous').on('click', function() {
  if (count !== 0) {
    count--;
    $('.product_image img').fadeTo(300, 0).delay(400).attr('src', '').attr('src', images[count]).finish().fadeTo(300, 1);
  }
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  display: block;
}
.navigation .previous,
.navigation .next {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navigation .next {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_image">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="previous">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) with callback function when complete like:

```js
var images = ['http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/kVy4G4R.jpg', 'http://i.imgur.com/BtMikrd.jpg'];

var count = 0;

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  if (count !== images.length - 1) {
    count++;
    $('.product_image img').fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', '').attr('src', images[count]).fadeTo(300, 1);
    });
  }
});

$('.previous').on('click', function() {
  if (count !== 0) {
    count--;
    $('.product_image img').fadeOut(300, function() {
      $(this).attr('src', '').attr('src', images[count]).fadeTo(300, 1);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.navigation {
  display: block;
}
.navigation .previous,
.navigation .next {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.navigation .next {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product_image">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/U82gG8H.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="previous">&lt;</div>
  <div class="next">&gt;</div>
</div>
```